# Can I get video clip/edit function as iOS Photos app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

like picture uploaded, I have an app want to use same function as photos app provided.

It should have these:

1. edit saved video, resize its area,such as cut top half of it's view.
2. drag to resize a new time interval video, such as 30 second video
   ,clip it to 16 second.

Thanks A lot!

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFJu8.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary)
   {
      let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
      imagePicker.delegate = self
      imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
      imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
      imagePicker.videoMaximumDuration = 300
      imagePicker.videoQuality = .Type640x480
      imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
      presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
```

Comment: Yes, I Finally find this,but it can't resize video area,or customise tool bar.

Comment: Just check this tutorial might help - https://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios